# AutoTest of all mappings in AutoMapperProfiles C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nunit, automapper

The question is to make a test that will look at each mapping from the MapperProfile and do a mapping test through .Map(model)

For Example:

```
private static IMapper _mapper;
public MappingAll()
{
    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
        mc.AddProfile(new Product());
        mc.AddProfile(new Apple());
    });
    var mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    _mapper = mapper;
}

[Test]
public void TestAll()
{
    MapperProvider tt = new MapperProvider(_mapper);
    // call some method to check all mappings specified in mappingConfig
    tt.CheckAllMappings();
}
```

I tried to implement it through reflection, but it didn't work fine.
There may also be a situation where mapping from an interface to a class can take place

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the mappings like this:

```
var sut = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<YourProfile>());
sut.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

You can generate test data with something like AutoFixture, but how would you work out that test data has been correctly moved across to the destination?

Comment: yes for manual testing. one test for one mapping i generate source object using AutoFaker or Mock
and I want to automate this by making one method that will take a list of mappings and check them. But there are problems because some fields may have special rules